# При запуске linux пишет что то непонятное

Tags: linux, загрузка

> /dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
>   /dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of corrupted orphan linked list found.
>
> /dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
>   (i. e., without -a or -p options)
>   fsck exited with status code 4
>   The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 reuires a manual fsck

[image: Экранный снимок вывода при загрузке]
Не особо шарю так что помогите исправить эту проблему.

Comment: Прочитайте сообщение и сделайте что там написано. И впредь делайте это до того, как просить о помощи.

Comment: Если перепечатаешь текст с картинки (для поисковика), то подробно расскажу, что произошло и что делать...

Comment: `fsck /dev/sda1` потом нажимаешь `Y` и если повезет то это дело закончится и после перезагрузки можно пользоваться системой дальше

Comment: Windows не нормальная ОС. я часа 2 фаервол там включал))

Comment: @eri ха, 2-а часа, это что, я его полгода выключаю,  а он обратно включается.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, перепечатал за вопрошающего. Но всё-таки вы злой.

Comment: @Arhad, извечная проблема, как поступать с неофитами, жёстко, поощряя самообучение или мягко, поощряя появление однообразных нудных вопросов... ИМХО по-настоящему злобно, хотя в каком-то ключе и правильней, было бы отослать ТС «в гугл», читать, что написано или поставить вопросу «дубликат»/«недооформлено» (хотя в предыдущем варианте ответы мне не особо понравились). Т.к. ТС не отвечал, то думаю, что он решил её ещё до моего комментария, всё же догадавшись обратиться в гугл или ещё-куда, а дальнейшее ему не особо было интересно... но хотя да, с тем, что я «злобный» я соглашусь.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте построчно разберём, чего же от нас хочет Linux:

> /dev/sda1 содержит файловую систему с ошибками; инициирована проверка.
>   /dev/sda1: были найдены inod-ы, являющиеся частью повреждённого связного списка.
>
> /dev/sda1: НЕОЖИДАННАЯ НЕСОГЛАСОВАННОСТЬ ДАННЫХ: ЗАПУСТИТЕ fsck ВРУЧНУЮ.
>   (т. е. без ключей -a и -p)
>   fsck завершила работу с кодом возврата 4
>   Корневая файловая система на /dev/sda1 требует ручного вызова fsck

В первых трёх строках нам сообщают, что на `/dev/sda1` имеются повреждения файловой системы. Однако они не настолько страшны (inode — это заголовок файловой записи). Единственное, что потеряется при восстановлении — уникальный номер и, как результат, путь до соответствующего файла; так что он будет помещён в папку `lost+found` в корне `/dev/sda1`. Главное, чтобы это не оказался какой-нибудь системный файл, ожидаемый во время загрузки ОС по конкретному пути.

Самой последней строкой вывода является `(busybox)`. Это приглашение командной строки минимальной версии консоли, внутрь которой вшит минимальный набор команд. Вариант аварийный, но его будет достаточно для «починки» раздела и перезагрузкив обычный режим.

Для «починки» введите команду:

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1 ; reboot -f
```

Первая часть (аналог Windows-ского `chkdsk`) выполнит проверку и безусловное (ключ `-y`) исправление ошибок; вторая выполнит перезагрузку сразу же по окончании этой операции.

*Кстати, вы не обесточивали компьютер прямо во время работы? Не выдёргивали диск, не отмонтировав его? Если нет, значит жёсткий диск начал «сыпаться», и по окончании проверки вам стоит как можно скорее скопировать всё его содержимое в другое место, пока ещё чего-нибудь не повредилось.*

Comment: Пары важных оговорк не хватает: 1)`fsck -y` **может** убить важные данные и/или всю ФС. Да, в реальности это случается крайне не часто (умозрительно я бы сказал, что 1 раз на 10000) и для этого обычно нужны необычные условия, но это нужно иметь ввиду. Так что я бы всё же посоветовал запустить сначала без `-y` и хотя бы посмотреть, что он предлагает исправить. Для корневой ФС обычно всё не так критично — в худшем случае не удастся загрузиться... 2) Если уж упомянул про «сыплющиеся» НЖМД, то лучше сказать про `smartctl`, а не про немедленный полный бекап..

Answer (score 1):

Моя история...
И так, была ошибка связанная с LVM сектором **/dev/mapper/ubuntu—vg-ubuntu—lv**

1. Попробовал исправить ошибки с диском из под винды - не помогло, Ubuntu также крашилась при загрузке с той же ошибкой lvm сектора
2. прогнал оперативку memtest86 (ошибок не было)
3. прогнал свой SSD диск финдовой утилитой

   chkdsk l: /f /r

(ошибок не было)

4. загрузился в режиме livedvd на той же виртуалке только с образа Ubuntu => ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso (т.е без установки см. видео https://youtu.be/XxD-LEpWEsg)
   и выполнил команду по восстановлению файловой системы (LVM как я понял )

   sudo fsck -y /dev/mapper/ubuntu—vg-ubuntu—lv

5)После чего удалил из загрузки виртуальной машины образ ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso, и запустил виртуальную машину.
Повились варианты загрузки, выбрал первый режим recovery, и затем выбрал "Resume normal boot",
после чего Ubuntu загрузилась в нормальном режиме и я сделал снимок состояния машины.

//команды для просмотра дисков и секторов

```
sudo fdisk -l 
sudo lvscan
sudo pvscan
```

//попробуйте поставить lvm2 на livedvd
//и повторить после установки

```
vgchange -a y
```

//а после vgchange если запустить

```
sudo lvscan
sudo vgscan
```